# Using JSON and gzip together in WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf, gzip

I need to create an endpoint on the server side (WCF) that will accept requests from the client that will contain headers:

```
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Encoding : gzip
Accept-Encoding : gzip
```

Is that possible complete without implementing custom MessageEncodingBindingElement?
Something like this:

```
 <customBinding>
     <binding name="gzipbinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
        <webMessageEncoding />
        <httpTransport/>
     </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

But it throw exception, because binding stack can contains only one encodingBindingElement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is only one encoding binding element allowed in the custom binding. In my opinion, we could achieve what you want in the following method. 
First, define the custom binding including the BinaryMessageEncoding and set compressionformat to Gzip.

```
<binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
```

Then, using the JSON string as the parameters to be passed.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

And the client fetches the value by deserializing the parameters.

```
Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(proxy.GetPersonDetailWithJson("123"));
```

One thing must be noted that in some specified case we should avoid json serialization since using json to serialized and deserialized the object needs time and resource (cpu, RAM).